# Modify Csv File by delete Rubbish Data and Storing the Data which need

Tags: c#, csv, ssis

I have a `.csv` file that look like this

```
Example Company                        
(999) 999-9999                      
http://yourwebsite.com                             
Report Date Range: Dec 26, 2013 - Dec 26, 2013                     
Exported: Dec 26, 2013                             
Twitter : Profile Summary                              
Screen Name,Name,Description,Location,Followers,Following,Listed

SctaSa,statisticalgraph,statistical Screen- The official account for your 
organization,Saudi Arabia,6775,8,75
```

So, I need to take specific data from the `.csv` file to be readable to SSIS Transformation, start from column `"Screen Name"` and add two columns `"Report Date Range"& "Exported"` which `existing in the row number 4&5` to put them in the end of column list after that put the data of these two columns in the end of data rows and `remove the garbage data`,to be look like that

```
Screen Name,Name,Description,Location,Followers,Following,Listed,Exported,Report Date Range
SctaSa,statisticalgraph,statistical Screen- The official account for your organization,Saudi Arabia,6775,8,75,26-Dec-13,26-Dec-13
```

I used this C# Script but did not give me the result which i need :

```
        public void UpdateCSV(string Pstring)        
        {  
            string[] values=File.ReadAllText("C:\\mycsv.csv").Split(new char[]{','});  
            StringBuilder ObjStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();  

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)  
            {  
                if (values[i] == Pstring)  
                    continue;  
                ObjStringBuilder.Append(values[i]+",");  
            }  
            ObjStringBuilder.ToString().Remove(ObjStringBuilder.Length - 1);  
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\UpdatedCSV.csv",ObjStringBuilder.ToString());  
       }
```

and i tried to use this C# script but it dose not work `(i'm not expert in C# so i don't know what's the problem)` i tried to use the following script to delete any line start with `#` could you give me any suggestions?!

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
}

    base.PreExecute();
    List<String> lines = new List<string>();
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\mycsv.csv");

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    lines.Add(line);
}

    lines.RemoveAll(l => l.Contains("#"));


    using (System.IO.StreamWriter outfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(outputPath))
{
    outfile.Write(String.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, lines.ToArray()));
}   
}
```

Comment: I'm Not expert in C# but i tried to fix this issue so i hope to find some one can help me in that :'(

Comment: please,I need to solve this problem because i'm in project

Comment: You can use the flat file connection manager. In which you can specify the number of rows to skip. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i Tried that, didn't give me the same result

Comment: Please take a look at the updated answer below. Hope it gives you some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps.

1. Create a two variables `ReportDateRange` and `Exported`.
2. Have script task in control flow.
3. Make `ReportDateRange` and `Exported` as read and write variable.
4. Use the following lines of code to extract the data from CSV file.

   ```
   var path = @"C:\mycsv.csv"
   Dts.variables["ReportDateRange "].value = File.ReadLines(path).ElementAtOrDefault(4);
   Dts.variables["Exported"].value = File.ReadLines(path).ElementAtOrDefault(5);
   ```
5. Use Data flow to extract the data from Flat file
6. Configure the connection manger as below screenshot
7. Use the Derived column transformation and Map the above said variables.

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: i tried it but The Problem it's a dynamic file not every time i will ignore first six rows

Comment: Can I delete any lines start from #

Comment: Otherwise, you can do one thing. Just create a file connection. Read all required data. After that use the conditional split to decide to load or not.